# How can I enter an unknown amount of values for array nums with a termination value of -1 in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Picture of what the program is supposed to do:

[image: screenshot 1]

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


    int main(){

    int nums[10],n,i=0;
    int s[10],popS[10];
    int sum=0;
    int numSum;
```

How can I enter an unknown amount of values for array nums with a termination value of -1?

```
    cout<<"Elements being placed in Stack,s"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    push(s,nums[i]);
    }

    cout<<"Popping the stack..."<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    popS[i]=pop(s);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i+=2){
    numSum=popS[i];
    sum+=numSum;

    }

    cout<<"The sum for every other element pop is "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

I am trying to enter values into array nums but the number of values isn't supposed to be known and terminated by -1.

Comment: Please post the problem statement as text, and show what work you've completed so far. There are too many concepts in here to give you the information from scratch.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of code here already. What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: In main i am supposed to have the user input data into the array nums(the amount of data is supposed to be unknown) and must be terminated by -1

Comment: What do you want to do if the user enters more than 10 valid numbers?

Comment: It wasnt specified  as you can see in the link above but call the isFull function and delete the rest

Comment: No, I mean you said you wanted to store the input values in the array first, which only has space for 10 `int`s. At the user input stage, you haven't pushed any items onto the stack yet.

Comment: After the 10 values gets inputted in the array,it is then taken from the array, nums and placed in the stack ,s

Comment: `s` only has space for 10 values though. Your options are 1. overwrite old data if the user enters more than 10 numbers or 2. stop accepting user input

Comment: can i stop accepting the data and also it terminate with -1 at the end of the values?

Comment: Yes, you can stop accepting input at either 10 values, or when the user enters a -1.

Comment: What would the code be if it stop accepting at -1.Could the user enter 12 values and it would only accept the first 10 and terminate by -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will accept user input until 10 `int`s have been received, or the user enters -1. The values will be placed in an array. User input is not checked to see that it is a valid int. Afterwards, `n` will hold the number of valid integers entered.

```
int nums[10];
std::size_t n = 0;
for (; n < 10; n++)
{
    int input;
    std::cin >> input;
    if (input == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    nums[n] = input;
}
```

Comment: bool isFull () {
    if (top == MAXLEN - 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}                                                                                                                                                                                    Would there be a way to call this function?If there are more than 10 values

Comment: Do you know how to call a function?

Comment: @Mithra I'm sorry, I am trying to understand what you want, but I'm having some difficulty. "Would there be a way to call this function if there are more than 10 values?" You can never hold more than 10 values in `nums`. When you're accepting input, it doesn't make sense to call `isFull()` because you haven't modified `top` at all.

Comment: I'll post another answer to show how to ignore any input beyond the 10th.

Answer (score 0):

This will accept the first 10 `int`s from user input until a -1 is entered. Any numerical input beyond the 10th will be ignored. User input is checked to see that it is a valid `int` in range. Any invalid input will exit the input loop. Afterwards, `n` will hold the number of valid integers entered, up to 10. If an invalid conversion was attempted (such as entering non-numeric input or a number out of range), handle the error

```
int input;
int nums[10];
std::size_t n = 0;
while (std::cin >> input)
{
    if (input == -1)
        break;

    if (n < 10)
    {
        nums[n++] = input;
    }    
}

if (std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear(); //clear the fail and bad bit
    std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX); // ignore any of the pending input that came after the offending conversion pattern
    std::cout << "Error reading input.\n";
    ...do some meaningful error handling. Exit the program likely.
}
```

Comment: Ok,sorry got a little confused with what to do if more than 10 values were entered.I thought it may caused an error.